# Metadata Query to get the list of all the mappings which contain a specific Stored procedure in Informatica

Tags: metadata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have some stored procedures and I need to get the list of all the mappings in informatica which have used that Stored Procedures. So i need METADATA query to get that list

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get folder,mapping, stored procedure and its name info-

```
select 
SUBJECT_AREA folder,  mapping_name, i.WIDGET_TYPE_NAME ,  INSTANCE_ID, INSTANCE_NAME, DESCRIPTION
from  
REP_WIDGET_INST i, REP_ALL_MAPPINGS m
where 
i.mapping_id = m.mapping_id and i.WIDGET_TYPE_NAME ='Stored Procedure'
order by 1, 2
```